# How to create in a for loop list unequal rows (2,4,3,2)

Tags: javascript, html, list, for-loop, shopify

I'm really hoping that you can help me.
I have a for loop

```html
  <ul>
  {% for product in collection.products  %}
     <li>{{product}}</li>
 {% endfor %}
 </ul>
```

I would like to create unequal rows:
first row - 2 products
second: 4
third 3
fourth: 2
fifth: 4
.....
And have something like this:

I'm trying to do this 2 month already. Could you please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want rows like

```
00 01
02 03 04 05
06 07 08
```

You can use that schema to create css classes like this

```
.col0, .col1{
  width: 50%;
}
.col2, .col3, .col4, .col5{
  width: 25%;
}
.col6, .col7, .col8{
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

And then in your code:

```
{% for product in collection.products %}
    <li class="col{{ forloop.index0 | modulo : 9}}">{{product.title}}</li> 
{% endfor %}
```

Note that this will work for an arbitrary number of elements. The final html will look like this

```
<ul>
<li class="col0">x</li>
<li class="col1">x</li>
<li class="col2">x</li>
<li class="col3">x</li>
<li class="col4">x</li>
<li class="col5">x</li>
<li class="col6">x</li>
<li class="col7">x</li>
<li class="col8">x</li>
<li class="col0">x</li>
<li class="col1">x</li>
<li class="col2">x</li>
...
</ul>
```

This is an example of the result.

```css
.col0, .col1{
  min-width: 50%;
}
.col2, .col3, .col4, .col5{
  min-width: 25%;
}
.col6, .col7, .col8{
  min-width: 33.3%;
}
ul{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
li{
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
}


li, just-for-better-display{
  background-color: #FAB100;
  border: 1px solid #0FAB10;
  margin: 5px -1px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="col0">1</li>
<li class="col1">2</li>
<li class="col2">3</li>
<li class="col3">4</li>
<li class="col4">5</li>
<li class="col5">6</li>
<li class="col6">7</li>
<li class="col7">8</li>
<li class="col8">9</li>
<li class="col0">10</li>
<li class="col1">11</li>
<li class="col2">12</li>
<li class="col2">13</li>
<li class="col2">14</li>
</ul>
```

Note that I've switched to `min-width` (and added `flex: 1`) to stretch the last elements to the maximum possible width.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what if I don't know how many rows it will be?
Because different categories have different amounts of products.

Comment: This will work with an infinite number of rows (that's why there is a "modulo"). The only issue could be the last row where it could be not complete. Please try and let me know if you have problems.

Comment: Hi Fabio, you are right!
Om mobile I've change layout to .col0, .col1{
  width: 50%;
} 
And I have "white space" after 14 products now.
Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @JulieR regarding the last row it depends what you want to achieve. I've updated the answer streching the width of the last elements. But otherwise `justify-content: space-between` can be enough. Let me know

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can do it with plain `liquid` itself without any tricks, but using js and css you will have a bit more freedom:

```
<ul id="collection-grid">
  {% for product in collection.products  %}
    <li>{{product}}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<style>
  ul#collection-grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  
  ul#collection-grid>li {
    display: block;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: -1px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  ul#collection-grid>li.col-6 {
    width: 50%
  }
  
  ul#collection-grid>li.col-3 {
    width: 25%
  }
  
  ul#collection-grid>li.col-4 {
    width: 33.3333%
  }

</style>


<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    const chunkConfig = [{
      items: 2,
      className: "col-6"
    }, {
      items: 4,
      className: "col-3"
    }, {
      items: 3,
      className: "col-4"
    }];
    const listItems = document.querySelectorAll("#collection-grid > li");
    for (let i = 0, chunkIndex = 0, chunkItemsCount = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
      const chunk = chunkConfig[chunkIndex];

      listItems[i].classList.add(chunk.className);

      if (++chunkItemsCount === chunk.items) {
        chunkItemsCount = 0;
        if (chunkIndex === chunkConfig.length - 1) chunkIndex = 0;
        else chunkIndex++;
      }
    }
  });

</script>
```

Just modify css a little to make it fit your needs.

UPD: I wrote this fiddle for tests purposes https://jsfiddle.net/4y8d1kvq/

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what if I don't know how many rows it will be? Because different categories have different amounts of products.

Comment: Same as in another answer in this question from @Fabio Filippi
- "This will work with an infinite number of rows. The only issue could be the last row where it could be not complete."

Answer (score 0):

- Main logic I have used is I have filtered the index like keeping only index of selected two and skip next three and stored it in `filteredProductIndexes`. and than check weather it contains an `index`  or not with `filteredProductIndexes.includes(index)`.
- `filteredProductIndexes.includes(index)` this will retunr `true` if index is there and `false` if not.
- if above condition satisfied than I have added class `.setHalf`, which has css of `flex:1 0 calc(50% - 30px);`(it means two items before wraping).
- and all the other `product` I have set css to `flex:1 0 calc(33.33% - 30px);` (this means three items before wrapping).
- Talking about `skipFilter(seq, pick, skip)` `pick` is how many item we want to select and `skip` is how many items we want to skip and `seq` is an array of indexes.
- I have found this function from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601553/javascript-for-loop-skip-2-numbers-followed-by-a-set-of-3/24601692#24601692) stackoverflow answer please visit that link for more information.
- **I am unsure why stackoverflow console is not loading but you can run this code in your project I have tested it on codepen and it works fine.**
  [image: Here is codepen screenshot]

```js
function skipFilter(seq, pick, skip) {
  var stride = pick + skip;

  return seq.filter(function(_, i) {
    return i % stride < pick;
  });
}
```

```js
const products = document.querySelectorAll(".product-container .product");
let productIndexes = [];
let pick = 2,
  skip = 3;
products.forEach((product, index) => {
  productIndexes.push(index);
})
filteredProductIndexes =
  skipFilter(productIndexes, pick, skip);

function skipFilter(seq, pick, skip) {
  var stride = pick + skip;

  return seq.filter(function(_, i) {
    return i % stride < pick;
  });
}
products.forEach((product, index) => {
  if (filteredProductIndexes.includes(index)) {
    product.classList.add("setHalf");
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.product-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.product-container .product {
  flex: 1 0 calc(33.33% - 30px);
}

.product-container .product.setHalf {
  flex: 1 0 calc(50% - 30px);
}

.product-container .product img {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="product-container">
    <li class="product">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </li>
    <li class="product">
      <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```